# Weird output with pelles c

Tags: c, pelles-c

```
float f=44268/107402;
printf("\n%f",f);
```

output :

> 0.000000

How can this happen!

I am using pelles c ide on win 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler treats the operands as integers. Try:

```
float f = 44268.0 / 107402;
                ^
```

Or maybe

```
float f = (float)44268 / 107402;
```

Comment: Thanks man.Now it returns 0.412171.But is still didn't get what's happening. It'll really help if can can you explain a bit?

Comment: when you use an integer to dive an integer, the answer will be an integer too. The number after `.` will be "delete". @user1187786

Answer (score 2):

`Integer division truncates`

```
float f=44268.0/107402;
```

Making one number float will automatically promote the other number ti float as well finally ending up in a floating point result.

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 44268 / 107402;
```

The variable will be initialize with an integer value. You should add a floating point, to say to the compiler that you want a float value.

```
float f = 44268. / 107402.;
```

Comment: I really appreciate the explanation.Now i get it.Once again thanks to everyone for helping me, it really bugging for almost an hour.